# Insert data and get back id in mybatis

Tags: spring, kotlin, mybatis

I should save the record in the database and get the record id in the response. After a long search and research I came up with the following option.

```
data class User(
    val id: UUID? = null,
    val username: String,
    ...
)
```

UserRepo:

```
   @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
    @Insert("""
        INSERT INTO "user" (
            username,
            ...
        ) VALUES (
            #{username},
            ...
        )
    """)
    fun save(user: User): User
```

in response I get the following.

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Mapper method '...UserRepository.save' has an unsupported return type: class ...entity.User
```

in the following case, I don't get an error, but I don't get an id either, how can I do it correctly? Used Select instead of Insert

```
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
@Select("""
    INSERT INTO "user" (
        username
    ) VALUES (
        #{username}
    )
""")
fun save(user: User): User
```

if we solve my first question, then I would like to know if it is possible to get the answer not in the User class, but in another one, for example, UserResponse? That is, send a request to the User class, and receive a response in the UserResponse

**UPDATE**
I was able to get the id after changing the id type to String.
Like this:

```
data class User(
    val id: String? = null,
    val username: String,
    ...
)
```

Apparently some settings are needed for UUID?
Has anyone faced such a problem?

Comment: The return type must be `void` or `int`. If you use `int`, the method returns the number of inserted rows. The generated key is set to the `id` property of the parameter instance. Regarding the second question, as I explained, MyBatis does not return a new instance at all, so, if you need an instance of `UserResponse`, you need to create it in your service layer or in a [default method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379364/1261766) of the mapper.

Comment: @ave i have posted update

Comment: You basically need to write a custom type handler. The actual implementation depends on the data type in DB (and this is why MyBatis does not provide a built-in type handler for UUID). This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622573/1261766) is for PostgreSQL's UUID type, for example.  The [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) explains how to register a custom type handler. If you use Spring Boot, you can set `mybatis.type-handlers-package` in application.properties.

Comment: about second question: How to use MyMapper interface? it is not clear

Comment: The caller (e.g. a service class) calls the default method defined in the mapper interface with a `User` instance as an argument. Then the default method 1) calls the `save` method defined in the same mapper interface, 2) creates a new instance of `UserResponse` (copying the properties of the `User` probably) and 3) returns the `UserResponse` instance. Please let me know if I misunderstand your question.

Comment: i dont get "The caller (e.g. a service class) calls the default method defined in the mapper interface with a User instance as an argument". UserService call method from interface?
Could you share a piece of code please?

Comment: For example, I have a UserService , a UserRepo with a save method, and an interface MyMapper that you suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246117/discussion-between-ave-and--).